# Proving $\arctan(\sinh(x))= 2\arctan(e^x) - \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, inverse-function

I’m attempting to prove this:
$$
f(x) = \arctan(e^x) \\
g(x) = \arctan(\sinh(x)) \\
\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
 g(x) = 2f(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Taking the tan of both sides, yields good results. However I'm unsure whether i can do that to the second part of this equation, as it lies within an interval larger than of $\left[\dfrac{-\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2\right]$.

Comment: Please use mathjax for your formatting, as it’s much more readable.

Comment: Use latex to write mathematical expressions.For mathjax basic tutorials for this website , please click here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/934187

Comment: Sorry, thank you for your remarks i rewrote it with Latex.

Comment: "the second part of this equation, as it lies within an interval larger than of [-π/2,π/2]": no, it lies within $2(0,\pi/2)-\pi/2=(0,\pi)-\pi/2=(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ so you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always take the tangent of both sides, since the values (of the RHS, which is what you are concerned about) are bounded between $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and both sides are monotonically increasing. You can see the boundedness as follows.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} 2 \arctan(e^{x})-\frac{\pi}{2}=0-\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

and

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 2 \arctan(e^{x})-\frac{\pi}{2}=2\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

If you take $\tan$ on both sides, you get for the left hand side
$\tan(\arctan(\sinh(x)))=\sinh(x)$
and for the right hand side
$\tan(2 e^{x}-\pi/2)=\frac{-1}{\tan(2 e^{x})}$.

Use the formula for $\tan(2x)=\frac{2 \tan(x)}{1-(\tan(x))^2}$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use this fact that, under certain conditions, if $f'(x)=g'(x)$ then for a constant $c$: $f(x)-g(x)=c$.

You can see [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj2ncnDm7n_AhW_SPEDHaFvDpcQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.usu.edu%2Fmath%2Frheal%2Fmath1210%2Flecture_notes%2FLecture_14_Comments.pdf&usg=AOvVaw097uNlmDcaIxpDn9oRvCHD) for more.